# Critical points question

Tags: calculus

Let $f'(x)=x^2+5x^4-e^{2x}+k$, where $k$ is a constant. If $f$ has 2 critical points, what is the value of $k$? 
I know critical points means the derivative is equal to zero, but after setting $f'(x)$ equal to zero I'm stuck... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks interesting -- the equation $f'(x) = 0$ does *not* depend on $k$...

Comment: @gt6989b Yes it does,  they gave $f'$,  not $f$

Comment: @Moo That is the original question, "Let $f'(x)$...what is the value of $k$?"

Comment: Can I ask you from which book this question is?

Comment: @Amelia My professor makes her own worksheets and this was a bonus question, I don't know if she made it herself or if it comes from a book.

Answer (score 2):

I am also stuck, so I graphed the function (I'm referring to $f'(x)$ as "the function" from now on) for some values of $k$. The plot resembles a cubic function, going to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to \mp\infty$ and with a local minimum and a local maximum. This in general intersects the $x$ axis either once or three times; we are looking for the values of $k$ for which the local maximum or local minimum coincides with the $x$ axis so that we have exactly two intersection points.

If I eyeball the values of $k$ using a slider, I find one of the values to be approximately $k\approx 2.36544$... I hope there is a better way to solve this, though. I am not sure if the question wants you to find an analytic or a numeric solution.

Here's a better way to solve it: we want the second derivative to vanish when the first derivative goes through the $x$ axis; we want both the first and second derivatives to vanish at the same time. If we take another derivative, we find
$$f''(x)=2x+20x^3-2e^{2x}=0 \Rightarrow e^{2x}=x+10x^3.$$ Subbing this into our equation for the first derivative, we find
$$x^2+5x^4-x-10x^3+k=0$$ subject to the earlier constraint on $x$. Technically, this could potentially be solved analytically by looking at the discriminant of the quartic polynomial and what it says about the number of possible roots (the discriminant will only be cubic in $k$, if that helps...), but I would more readily use a numerical method to solve this.

Comment: K around -54.05 another solution.